# Schur's Lemma of the Version for Lie Algebras

Tags: modules, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, representation-of-algebras

In general, Schur's lemma is stated as follows.

> (i) Let $(\pi_1,V_1)$ and $(\pi_2,V_2)$ be irreducible
> representations, and let $T:V_1\rightarrow V_2$ be an intertwining
> operator. Then either $T$ is zero or it is an isomorphism.
>
> (ii) Suppose that $(\pi,V)$ is an irreducible representation of $G$
> and $T:V\rightarrow V$ is an intertwining operator. Then there exists
> a scalar $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $T(v)=\lambda v$ for all
> $v\in V$.

Now I'm considering the Lie algebras' version of Schur's lemma in Exercise 10.5 in *Lie Groups* by Daniel Bump.

> Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra, and let $V$, $W$ be
> simple $\mathfrak{g}$-modules.
>
> (i') The space of $\mathfrak{g}$-module homomorphisms
> $\phi:V\rightarrow W$ is at most one-dimensional.
>
> (ii') The space of invariant bilinear forms $V\times W\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is at most one-dimensional.

Here are my idea and question to verify Schur's lemma of the version for Lie Algebras:

One can conclude (i') immediately from (i) if *there exists an irreducible representation for any Lie algebra* (how to demonstrate it or where can I find the result about it?). We may obtain (ii') by a proposition in Bump's *Lie Groups*:

> **Proposition 10.5.** Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite-dimensional simple
> Lie algebra over a field $F$. Then there exists, up to scalar, at most
> one invariant bilinear form on $\mathfrak{g}$. If a nonzere invariant
> bilinear form exists it is nondegenerate and symmetric.

Can we **generalize Proposition 10.5 in the case that $\mathfrak{g}$ is an arbitrary Lie algebra** to conclude (ii')? Moreover, what's the relation between the above two versions of Schur's lemma?

Comment: Any Lie algebra has an irreducible representation - the trivial $1$-dimensional one.

Comment: The claim in $(i')$ and $(ii')$ is false for arbitrary $\mathfrak{g}$-modules $V$ and $W$. They need to be simple.

Comment: This is an exercise from Bump’s *Lie Groups* and I’m trying to figure it out. Thanks for your hints and comments that reminded me there should add some more information to this exercise!

Comment: Schur's Lemma is essentially the fact that the center of the full matrix algebra is the multiples of the identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. We may add some information to the original exercise, that $V$ and $W$ should be simple $\mathfrak{g}$-modules.

For (i'), since simple $\mathfrak{g}$-module is already an irreducible representation, by (i), the space of $\mathfrak{g}$-module homomorphisms is at most one-dimensional.

For (ii'), since a bilinear form $V\times W\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ gives a $\mathfrak{g}$-linear map from $V$ to the dual of $W$, and it follows that it is an intertwining operator. Then applying (i) we can conclude what we desire.